# jCarouselLite container with round corners

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dramatically need help with my slider. It must have round corners. I'm using jCarousellLite, which code you can find here: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js .

My own code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".newsticker-jcarousellite").jCarouselLite({
        vertical: true,
        visible: 6,
        auto:1000,
        speed:500
    });
});

</script>
```

```
            <div class="newsticker-jcarousellite" style="float:left;width:120px;border-top-left-radius:20px">
                <ul>
                    <li><img style="width:110px;height:165px" src="http://www.minusport.ee/files/images/reklaam.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img style="width:110px;height:165px" src="http://www.minusport.ee/files/images/reklaam.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img style="width:110px;height:165px" src="http://www.minusport.ee/files/images/reklaam.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img style="width:110px;height:165px" src="http://www.minusport.ee/files/images/reklaam.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img style="width:110px;height:165px" src="http://www.minusport.ee/files/images/reklaam.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img style="width:110px;height:165px" src="http://www.minusport.ee/files/images/reklaam.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img style="width:110px;height:165px" src="http://www.minusport.ee/files/images/reklaam.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img style="width:110px;height:165px" src="http://www.minusport.ee/files/images/reklaam.jpg" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The border radius for the div doensnt work, and I know why, but I do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with overflow hidden:

```
<div class="newsticker-jcarousellite" style="float:left;width:120px;border-top-left-radius:20px;overflow:hidden">
```

Comment: The element already has overflow:hidden rule made by jCarousell. This did not work.